# Export Products on a Category

Tags: category, products, csv, export

Is there a way that I can export all products on a certain category via CSV or excel file?

Answer (score 0):

**Create one file on your magento root directory and add below code in that file.**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Mage::app();

$categoryId = 14; // category Id for which you want products

$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect("*");
$products->addCategoryFilter($category);

$fileName = 'exports_'.$category->getId().'.csv';

$fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');

$csvHeader = array("sku", "name"); // you can specify more fields which you need in export file

fputcsv($fp, $csvHeader, ",");

foreach ($products as $product) {

    $sku = $product->getSku();

    $name = $product->getName();

    fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $name), ",");
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

**If you have permission issue on magento root you can export in var or media folder as well.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically by using following code:

```
<?php  
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::getIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_get('display_errors', 1);
    ini_get('memory_limit', '600M');
    ini_get('max_execution_time', 1800);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin'); 
    $fileLocation = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'productlist.csv' ;//file path of 
    $mageCsv = new Varien_File_Csv();
    $categoryId = 46; //put your cat id here
    $productsModel =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
                        ->getProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) 
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) ;
    $productsRow = array();
    foreach ($productsModel  $product)
    {
        $data = array();

        $data['id']         = $product->getId();
        $data['name']       = $product->getName();
        $data['sku']        = $product->getSku();
        $data['weight']     = $product->getWeight();
        $data['urlkey']     = $product->getUrlKey();
        $data['price']      = $product->getPrice();
        $data['metatitle']  = $product->getMetaTitle();
        $data['metakey']    = $product->getMetaKeyword();
        $data['metadesc']   = $product->getMetaDescription();
        $data['disc']       = $product->getDescription();
        $data['sdic']       = $product->getShortDescription();
        // you other product attribute goes here

        $productsRow[] = $data;
    }   
    $mageCsv->saveData($fileLocation, $productsRow); 
    echo 'done!'
    ?>
```

You need to put this file on your root folder and run via url, when script complete the process check your media folder.

Answer (score 0):

here is my version too:

```
// Avoid any time limit
set_time_limit(0);

// Avoid any memory limit
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

// Include bootstrap code and Mage class
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// Enable developer mode
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

// Set the default file creation mask
umask(0);

// Init application with default store
Mage::app();

// Init admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// Load adminhtml config area
Mage::app()->loadArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);

// Initialize administrator session
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$administrator = $userModel->load(1); // change administrator id here
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminSession->renewSession();
$adminSession->setUser($administrator);
$acl = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl();
$adminSession->setAcl($acl);

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$products = $category
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name'); // add needed attributes

$csvColumns = array('entity_id', 'sku', 'type_id', 'name');

$csvData = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $csvData[] = array_map(
        function($column) use ($product) {
            return $product->getData($column);
        },
        $csvColumns
    );
}

$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->saveData('/tmp/products.csv', array($csvColumns) + $csvData);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your root directory and upload the **getproductlist.php**.
Inside the directory create a sub directory called **csv**.

Below is the code for **getproductlist.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
function array2csv(array &$array, $name_extension=null) {

    if (count($array) == 0) {return null;} 

    $name_extension = date('m-d-Y', strtotime("yesterday"))."_".time();

    $FileName = "csv/Product_list"."-".$name_extension.".csv";
    echo "Download as CSV file: <a href='$FileName'>Download</a>";

    $df = fopen($FileName, 'w');
    $titles = array();


    array_push($titles, "id", "name", "sku", "urlkey", "price", "metatitle", "metakey", "metadesc", "disc", "sdic");
    $blankArray = array("","","","","","","","","","");
    fputcsv($df, $titles);


    foreach ($array as $row) {
        fputcsv($df, $row);
    }

    fclose($df);

}//END OF Function array2csv

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', 16);
                //Give the relevant category id which you want to import.
$m=0;
$itsmArr = array();
foreach ($collection as $product)   {
 $prod_id = $product->getId();
 $_product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());   

    $prd['id']         = $_product->getId();
    $prd['name']       = $_product->getName();
    $prd['sku']        = $_product->getSku();
    $prd['weight']     = $_product->getWeight();
    $prd['urlkey']     = $_product->getUrlKey();
    $prd['price']      = $_product->getPrice();
    $prd['metatitle']  = $_product->getMetaTitle();
    $prd['metakey']    = $_product->getMetaKeyword();
    $prd['metadesc']   = $_product->getMetaDescription();
    $prd['disc']       = $_product->getDescription();
    $prd['sdic']       = $_product->getShortDescription();

 $itsmArr[$m] = array($prd['id'],$prd['name'], $prd['sku'],$prd['urlkey'],$prd['price'],$prd['metatitle'],$prd['metakey'],$prd['metadesc'],$prd['disc'],$prd['sdic']); 
 echo $prd['id']."-".$prd['name']."</br>";
$m++;
}
array2csv($itsmArr,"");
?>
```

You can use what ever fields you want to get from the product collection.
I hope this will help you or some one in future.